# Using Majority Voting to combine groups across multiple lists

Tags: r, list, loops, grouping, purrr

I have a bunch of samples and a bunch of lists where each element of each list is a group containing all or some of the samples (each group will always have at least one sample). Moreover, each list does not need to contain all the samples but all samples will be always be contained across all the entries of all of the lists.

I want to use a majority vote across all the lists and their entries (i.e the sample groups) to create a final list that contains new groupings of all of the samples. If a sample occurs in only 1 list and its part of a group, that sample will get bundled in with whatever final group the majority of its original grouped samples are in.

I have created a toy example below that outlines the problem.

FYI, the solution does not need to be a list manipulation, if a solution can be found using data frames/matrices/vectors whatever that will work too. If a loop of some sort is required that is fine too!

I am struggling to even see how to approach this problem. Hopefully the snippet below makes it a bit more clearer what I mean than the description :)

```
all_samples <- paste0("sample_",1:10)

list1 <- list()
list1[[1]] <- c("sample_1","sample_2","sample_3","sample_4")
list1[[2]] <- c("sample_5", "sample_6")
list1[[3]]<- c("sample_8", "sample_9","sample_10")

list2 <- list()
list2[[1]] <- c("sample_1","sample_2")
list2[[2]] <- c("sample_5", "sample_6")
list2[[3]]<- c("sample_7","sample_8", "sample_9","sample_10")


list3 <- list()
list3[[1]] <- c("sample_1","sample_2")
list3[[2]] <- c("sample_3")
list3[[3]] <- c("sample_5", "sample_6")
list3[[4]]<- c("sample_7","sample_8", "sample_9")
list3[[5]] <- c("sample_10")



list4  <- list()
list4[[1]] <- c("sample_1","sample_2")
list4[[2]] <- c("sample_6")
list4[[3]] <- c("sample_8", "sample_10")
list4[[4]] <- c("sample_3")

desired_output <- list(
  c("sample_1","sample_2","sample_4"),
  c("sample_3"),
  c("sample_5", "sample_6"),
  c("sample_7","sample_8", "sample_9", "sample_10")
)
```

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? 1) A single list can have any length? `list1` is of length 3, `list3` is of length 5. 2) In the final output none of the samples are repeated and all of them are included exactly once? 3) `desired_output` is not fixed, there could be multiple combinations of it ? 4) You randomly select any value from any list such that 2) is satisified?

Comment: hi. 1) Yes. A single list can be of any length. The only condition is that each element must contain at least 1 sample. 2) Yes this is correct. 3) is partially correct, i.e. it is not of fixed length. The combination of the sample groups (elements in `desired_output `)is based on which samples occur together most frequently in the original lists. 4) The group selections are not random, they are the most frequently grouped samples in the original lists

Comment: So to clarify the example `sample_1` & `sample_2` occur together in all 4 lists. `sample_3` is in its own group 2/4 times and once with `sample_1` and `sample_2` so by majority rule it becomes its own group. `sample_4` occurs only once so it gets added to the group where it has the most number of samples from the original list. Hence the 1st two elements of `desired_output`  are `c("sample_1","sample_2","sample_4")` and `c(sample_3)`. Similarly with the  last 2 elements of `desired_output`